# In Oracle Is there a way to check if the procedure ran successfully at a specific time or not?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, dbms-scheduler

At my workplace, I've got some procedures, that are supposed to run automatically, at a specific time, but sometimes they fail.

I come to know about the failure of procedures about 1-2 hrs after the failure, that too if i manually check it.

What i'm trying to do now that if a procedure fails, i should receive a mail on my email id.But, for that i need a way to track the status of procedure run.
Is there any way in oracle where i can track whether the procedure run was successful or not , within 15 minutes of the procedure run.
Does oracle creates any kind of logs that says so?

Comment: Why is this tagged for both Oracle and MySQL?  How are the procedures being run?  Via a `dbms_job` or `dbms_scheduler` job?  Via some external scheduler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `dbms_scheduler` to run the job, you would just need to consult the [`[dba|all|user]_scheduler_job_run_details` table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_1140.htm#i1587156) to see information about the job log information.  That includes things like when the job was scheduled to be run, when it actually ran, how long it ran, whether there was an error, etc.